# Iteration over list and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I am trying to reduce execution time of my loop wich mainly consist of reading data in a list, do some computation on it and writing result in a array.

I try these tests on a 20 000 000 elements list on quad core CPU:

1. Single thread for loop
2. 4 threads one for loop in each thread iterate 1/4 of the list

It seems that the single thread is faster than 4 threads (i have try also with 2).

I was wondering why ??? I think the problem is I/O throughput, but i am really frustrated to have processor used at 25% and waiting for computation.

Is there any solution to improve/parallelize iteration over a list ?

Is the memory the limitating factor ?

**EDIT : Code added**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20_000_000).forEach(i -> li.add(i));

    Integer[] tab = new Integer[1000];
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 999).forEach(i -> tab[i] = 0);

    System.out.println("debut");
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadRunner(li, tab, 1, 0));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadRunner(li, tab, 4, 1));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadRunner(li, tab, 4, 2));
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new ThreadRunner(li, tab, 4, 3));

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("time : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

}
```

}

```
public class ThreadRunner implements Runnable {

List<Integer> l;
private int inc;
private int start;
private Integer[] tab;

public ThreadRunner(List<Integer> l, Integer[] tab, int inc, int start) {
    this.l = l;
    this.inc = inc;
    this.start = start;
    this.tab = tab;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int fake = 0;
    for(int i = start; i<l.size(); i+=inc){

        fake = l.get(i);

    }

    System.out.println("fake : " + fake);

}
```

}

Comment: Share the code, please.

Comment: This is *entirely* code and algorithm dependent.  First, the problem has to lend itself to being parallelizable.  Then, the parallel code has to be written to take advantage of that.

Comment: You are right i will post it asap. but it's minimalist for loop over a list and add 1 to a array element (the element is chosen whith list index modulo 1000) i run 4 thread and i wait with join(). Each loop advance 4 element further in the list

Comment: Don't waste time writing out what the code does in English, the devil is in the detail and the detail is in the code.

Comment: Yes your right i wasn't on the right pc when i post the question sorry

Comment: Why does one of your threads have an `inc` of `1`? It will being do 4 times the work of the others.

Comment: Wrong copy-paste in stackoverflow i have already correct this mistake

Answer (score 0):

Starting threads and then waiting for them to complete takes a bit of time. I suspect that time is much greater that the time it takes to iterate over a few million elements in a list.

What makes you believe this is the most important part of your code to optimize, and that spawning threads will speed it up?

Remember the rules of whe to optimize: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Note: the way you are measuring execution time may so be misleading you. Writing microbenchmarks is very tricky.

Comment: Yeah i understand. But in the real code i have much more computation in the for loop and with single or 4 thread i have 2s execution i dont think thread management overhead take that time. I really think memory ils the limiting factor ans i want your opinions

Comment: Did you measure where the time is being spent (perhaps with a profiler)? Also, read https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks before writing a benchmark

Answer (score -2):

Java can not decide which core it uses. Your OS will make that decision. So your 4 threads are indeed running on one core.

Comment: We don't know that for sure.  Not until the code is added.

Comment: yeah it's a good point that i don't think about but I run many test and i saw processor load increase by 25% by added thread